# How to create a minimal OpenXML text (sub)document that holds a single figure with caption, and does not specify styles?

Tags: openxml

I'd like to implement a small helper tool that allows me to create the bare minimum of an OpenXML text document that will hold a single figure, and its caption, but nothing else. Ideally it should not specify paper size, margins, styles, etc.

Just the figure, the caption, and that's it. Eventually I then want to include those figure "subdocuments" into the document proper for the final typesetting step.

How does the minimal structure of such a OpenXML package look like? Does it need placeholder files? Does the image specification in the `document.xml` require the use of `<AlternativeContent>` switch, or can a single content relation be specified?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, by "OpenXML text document" you mean a word file. If so, then yes, an image in the document.xml does not require an `AlternateContent` block, only the image.

You can create document with just an image and its caption without specifying the paper size and margins, which are specified in the document.xml part's sectPr element, which are optional, so the document.xml is still valid if they're not specified. The styles are defined in the styles.xml part, which requires a styles element at the root, but it does not require any other elements or styles be specified.

If you want to manipulate the xml of an OpenXml file, the best tool is probably  https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK